# Editar formulário Laravel

Tags: formulário, laravel-5.3

[image: Tela do formulário]

Galera, como faço pra trazer o curso que o aluno foi cadastrado nesta parte de edição do formulário. Ele traz a lista dos cursos mas queria que já viesse com o curso que o aluno foi cadastrado.

Segue o FORM

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    Foto:<br>
                    <label for="selecao-arquivo">
                        <img id="view-img" src="{{asset('fotos/'.$a>foto)}}">
                        <input id="selecao-arquivo" type="file" name="foto" value="{{'fotos/'.$a->foto}}">
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-5 form-group">
                    Nome:
                    <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" value="{{ $a->nome }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                    Tel.:
                    <input type="text" name="telefone" class="form-control" value="{{ $a->telefone }}">
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-5 form-group">
                    E-mail:
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $a->email }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
                    Curso:
                    <select name="idcurso" class="form-control" required>
                        <option></option>
                        @foreach($lista as $c)
                            <option value="{{$c->idcurso}}">
                                {{$c->nomecurso}}
                            </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </fieldset><br>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-2 form-group">
                Cep:
                <input id="cep" type="text" name="cep" class="form-control" value="{{ $a->endereco->cep }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                Endereço:
                <input id="endereco" type="text" name="endereco" class="form-control" value="{{ $a->endereco->endereco }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 form-group col-xs-offset-2">
                Bairro:
                <input id="bairro" type="text" name="bairro" class="form-control" value="{{ $a->endereco->bairro }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
                Cidade:
                <input id="cidade" type='text'  name="cidade" class="form-control" value="{{ $a->endereco->cidade }}">    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                Estado:
                <input id="estado" type='text'  name="estado" class="form-control" value="{{ $a->endereco->estado }}">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="ATUALIZAR" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-offset-2">
        {{csrf_field()}}
    </form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function  detalhes($id, Request $request){
$data = array();
$data["lista"] = \App\Curso::all();
try{
    $alu = \App\Aluno::find($id);
    if($request->isMethod("POST")){
        $matricula = $request->input("matricula", "");
        $nome = $request->input("nome", "");
        $telefone = $request->input("telefone", "");
        $sexo = $request->input("sexo", "");
        $email = $request->input("email", "");
        $endereco = $request->input("endereco", "");
        $bairro = $request->input("bairro", "");
        $cep = $request->input("cep", "");
        $cidade = $request->input("cidade", "");
        $estado = $request->input("estado", "");
        $idcurso = $request->input("idcurso", "");

        $file = $request->file("foto");

        /* Caso o usuário não tenha enviado uma nova foto, ignora o trecho abaixo */
        if ($file != null) {
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $size = $file->getSize();

            if($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "png" && $ext != "jpeg"){
                $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>"
                        . "Escolha uma IMAGEM valida</div>";
                //2MB
            }else if($size > (1024 * 1024 * 2)){
                $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>"
                        . "Tamanho da imagem invalido</div>";
            }

            $fileName = "ft_" .date('YmdHis').".".$ext;

            $alu->foto = $fileName;
        }


        $alu->matricula = $matricula;
        $alu->nome = $nome;
        $alu->telefone = $telefone;
        $alu->sexo = $sexo;
        $alu->email = $email;
        $alu->idcurso = $idcurso;

        $alu->save();

        $idend = $alu->endereco->idendereco;

        $e = \App\Endereco::find($idend);

        $e->endereco = $endereco;
        $e->bairro = $bairro;
        $e->cidade = $cidade;
        $e->cep = $cep;
        $e->estado = $estado;

        $e->aluno()->associate($alu);

        $e->save();

        // Caso o usuário não tenha enviado uma foto, ignora o trecho abaixo.
        if ($file != null) {
            $file->move("fotos", $fileName);
        }

        $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>"
                . "Aluno editado com sucesso!</div>";

        $alu = \App\Aluno::find($id);

        return redirect('admin/buscar.html');

    }

    $data["a"] = $alu;

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $data["resp"] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"
            . "Operação não realizada</div>";
}

return view('aluno/detalhes', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse trecho [html](/questions/tagged/html) faça a comparação se for o mesmo `idcurso` atribua no option a propriedade `selected`, que vai posicionar no `idcurso` cadastrado em sua tabela, exemplo:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
    Curso:
    <select name="idcurso" class="form-control" required>
        <option></option>
        @foreach($lista as $c)
        <option value="{{$c->idcurso}}" @if ($a->idcurso == $c->idcurso) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>
                {{$c->nomecurso}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Beleza, funcionou mas no Netbeans aparece como se a estrutura do código estivesse incorreta.

Comment: @vando o que importa que essa é o código que precisa, talvez no NetBeans esteja com algum problema ou não interpreta as `tag` blade corretamente! Se for util marque como resposta do seu post.